# Load 2 million entries of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, import, dump

I am trying to import a dump file to MySQL through command line. The dump file contains about 2 million entries. To import the data I used the command `mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < filename.sql` . The problem is that **the process started 24 hours ago and it's still going** while it imported merely 50% of the data. Is there any option I could add to the command to  make the process faster or is there any  other command I could use? The dump file is available in `.sql` and `.sql.gz` format. I also tried to import the sql.gz file but it gives an error saying that there is an error at line 1 with some quote.

Thanks!

Comment: How large is the dump file?

Comment: How many index/uniques/etc. hast the target table?

Comment: the sql file is 685 MB, the sql.gz is 70 . There are many tables, not a single one. The biggest table has about 1.5 million records with 4 keys i think

Comment: Does the "dump file" contain a single `INSERT` statement with multiple rows in a single `VALUES` clause?  Or are there millions of separate `INSERT` statements?  In any event, you would probably be better loading this much data with `LOAD DATA` or `mysqlimport` from a data file in delimited format.

Comment: When I exported the data I chose to add the INSERT for every row

Comment: @eggyal Just our of curiosity (not a DB expert), would you know difference in speed if using LOAD DATA or mysqlimport and why?  Would it be trivial or 2x faster or 3x faster?  I'm asking cause we import 12GB dumps and it takes forever!  I've tried finding a way to delay indexing during insertion till all inserts were done, which I believe which be much faster.  But I have not found this feature or proof that this would help.

Comment: @Jeach: According to [Speed of `INSERT` Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-speed.html) (emphasis added): "*When loading a table from a text file, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html). **This is usually 20 times faster than using [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statements.***"